# Google Sheets - results of formula in wrong cell

Tags: xml, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In google sheets, i made a table with lists of film and also with link with reviews.
Based on those reviews I wanted to scrap average percentage out of the website so I write a formula like in the picture.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8S7WW.png)

But problem is that result 59% this formula put also into the next cell like a text. Looks like this.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOvLH.png)

When I overwrite that cell with doubled outcome, it looks like this.[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMqMm.png) Previous result end up like "ref and situation with doubled outcome is there again.

What I am doing wrong?

I just want to have percentage in one cell next to name of the film, but I really dont know what else to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try:

```
=importxml(D2;"//aside[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]")
```

[image]